# placing links correctly using ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create some sort of a sticky note using the css from step 1 in the following link
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/create-a-sticky-note-effect-in-5-easy-steps-with-css3-and-html5/

I am using ruby on rails to generate the notes with the following code

```
<ul>
      <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <li>
          <a>    
             <p><strong>Title:</strong>
             <%= post.title %></p>

          </a>
     </li>
     <% end %>
</ul>
```

everything is working fine but when I am trying to add a link to the post I am getting the link added in a different post

for example

```
<ul>
      <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <li>
          <a>    
             <p><strong>Title:</strong>
             <%= post.title %>
             <%= link_to 'Show', post, :class => 'text' %></p>

          </a>
     </li>
     <% end %>
</ul>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Why use `link_to` on link tag?

Comment: meaning? this is how scaffolding generated it. as you can tell i am new to ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul>
 <% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <li>
 <%= link_to post, :class => 'text' do %>
   <p>
     <strong>Title:</strong>
     <%= post.title %>
   </p>
 <% end %>
 </li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

[link_to method rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)